# Strange host IP Addresses showing up in Awstats

Tags: ip-address, shared-hosting, awstats

I've just put up a website and checking Awstats a couple of days later I noticed a number of strange IP addresses showing up - wondering if anyone knows what this means, in amongst a list of legitimate IP Addresses including Google bot IP's

```
2001:8003:3541:4a00:80b2:1fd9:12d1:88b2
2001:8003:207d:f600:4c7f:34ab:5e3a:c16c
2a03:2880:2130:9ff0:face:b00c:0:1
2401:a400:4506:d700:ad6b:88b3:7bc2:43f0
2001:8000:1048:3700:654a:2020:22d0:80dc
2001:8003:652a:9600:6001:2418:e1c1:f8c2
2a03:2880:2130:9ff5:face:b00c:0:1
```

Comment: There are an IPv6 IP number. It seems are correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Those are valid [IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6). 
IPs like `1.1.1.1` are IPv4